# programming snake in c# with console

Tags: c#, console, logic, ascii

I'm trying to make a snake in the console to keep me in training in c #. I have a problem in the movement. To test I wanted to do so by pressing the letter "a" would shift the "food" on the X I noticed that in terms of graphics, but does not move through a Console.Write is incremented. Can you give me a hand? I am attaching the main classes, world food

Main:

```
namespace Snake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            char s;
            World mondo = new World(20, 10);
            do
            {
                s = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                mondo.update();
                mondo.drawWorld();

            }

            while (s == 'a');

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

World:

```
namespace Snake
{
    class World
    {
        public int larghezza;
        public int altezza;
        public int sizeSnake = 3;
        public Food food;
        public Snake[] snake;
        public Snake s;

        public enum Box { FREE , FOOD, SNAKE };//0,1,2
        public Box[,] size;


        public World(int larghezza, int altezza)
        {
            this.larghezza = larghezza;
            this.altezza = altezza;
            size = new Box[larghezza, altezza];
            food = new Food();
            snake = new Snake[sizeSnake];
            s = new Snake();
            food.InstaceFood(altezza, larghezza);
            size[food.pos.x,food.pos.y] = Box.FOOD;

            for (int i = 0; i < sizeSnake; i++)
            {
                snake[i] = s;
                snake[0].startSnake(altezza, larghezza);
                size[snake[i].pos.x-i, snake[i].pos.y] = Box.SNAKE;
            }


       }

        public void update()
        {

           // snake[0].move(snake);
            food.moveee();
        }

        public void control (Box type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case Box.FOOD:
                     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                     Console.Write('X');
                     Console.ResetColor();
                     break;

                case Box.FREE:
                     Console.Write(' ');
                     break;
                case Box.SNAKE:
                     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                     Console.Write('█');
                     Console.ResetColor();
                     break;

            }

        }




        public void drawWorld()
        {

            Console.Write('╔');
            for (int i = 0; i < larghezza; i++)
            {
                Console.Write('═');
            }
            Console.Write('╗');

            for (int i = 0; i < altezza; i++)
            {
                Console.Write('\n');

                for (int j = 0; j < larghezza; j++)
                {

                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write('║');
                    }

                       control(size[j,i]);

                        if (j == larghezza - 1)
                        Console.Write('║');
                }

            }
            Console.Write('\n');
            Console.Write('╚');
            for (int i = 0; i < larghezza; i++)
            {
                Console.Write('═');
            }
            Console.WriteLine('╝');
        }
    }
}
```

Food:

```
namespace Snake
{
    class Food
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        public Vector2 pos;

        public Food()
        {

        }


        public void InstaceFood(int _Altezza, int _Larghezza)
        {

            int rndY = rnd.Next(0, _Altezza);
            int rndX = rnd.Next(0, _Larghezza);
            pos.x = rndX;
            pos.y = rndY;
        }

        public void moveee()
        {
            this.pos.x += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Vector2:

```
namespace Snake
{
    struct Vector2
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Vector2(int xx, int yy)
        {
            x = xx;
            y = yy;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time actually figuring out what your problem is with the way your question is worded. Could you try to clarify what, exactly, your problem is?

Comment: the problem is that the function move in the class "food" is not working properly. The food should I move it (a test) but in terms of graphics is not moving

Comment: Do you already have a working snake moving through your world yet or are you just starting with the food?

Comment: It is good that you provided code, but be careful to follow the **minimal** part of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question. Part of minimal is "Restart from scratch"... I find that I can often figure out the issue myself when I do that step.

Comment: for now I have it initialized. I wanted to move the food to see the result, then I will move the snake

Answer (score 0):

The food does not move because you are not updating `Box[,] size` with the new values.  Try this modification:

```
public void update()
{
  // snake[0].move(snake);
  size[food.pos.x, food.pos.y] = Box.FREE;
  food.moveee();
  size[food.pos.x, food.pos.y] = Box.FOOD;
}
```